# display rows as column

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot, dynamic-pivot

I want to display rows as column in SQL Server.

My table looks like this:

```
images_id  item_id  images_name
-------------------------------
1          1        image1.jpg 
2          1        image2.jpg 
3          1        image3.jpg 
4          2        image4.jpg 
5          2        image5.jpg 
6          2        image6.jpg
```

I'd like this output:

```
images_id  item_id  image1      image2      image3    
------------------------------------------------------
1          1        image1.jpg  image2.jpg  image3.jpg
2          2        image4.jpg  image5.jpg  image6.jpg
```

Here is an [image link](http://i26.tinypic.com/29e4oap.jpg).

Is this possible or not? item_id must be dynamically changeable (it is not stable).

Comment: +1: For being upfront about needing a dynamic pivot query.  I updated the tags, you should be able to find numerous examples while you're waiting.

Comment: Here's a link: [Using PIVOT and UNPIVOT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410.aspx). I don't know if the dynamic id is easily acheivable with this though.

Comment: @OMG Ponies: I see you put the image into the question just before I changed it to text (for ease of copy + pasting). The image does look better. You can put the image back if you prefer images. :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get ROWS as COLUMNS (SQL Server dynamic PIVOT query)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12074939/get-rows-as-columns-sql-server-dynamic-pivot-query)

Answer (score 2):

[Cross Tabs and Pivots, Part 1 – Converting Rows to Columns](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/T-SQL/63681/)

[Cross Tabs and Pivots, Part 2 - Dynamic Cross Tabs](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Crosstab/65048/)

[Pivot table for Microsoft SQL Server](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Advanced+Querying/pivottableformicrosoftsqlserver/2434/)

Answer (score 0):

This isn't possible without using dynamic SQL.  PIVOT requires you to specify the columns still.

Let me know if dynamic SQL is acceptable and I'll spin you an example.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you can use Dynamic SQL for this:

```
DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

SET @cols = STUFF((SELECT distinct ',' + QUOTENAME('image' + cast(row_number() over(partition by itemid order by imageid) as varchar(5))) 
            FROM test c
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'')

set @query = 'SELECT itemid, ' + @cols + ' from 
            (
                select itemid, imagename, 
                  ''image'' + cast(row_number() over(partition by itemid order by imageid) as varchar(5)) col
                from test
           ) x
            pivot 
            (
                min(imagename)
                for col in (' + @cols + ')
            ) p '


execute(@query)
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/832f1/16)