# Write advanced SQL Select

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, pivot

Item table:

```
|   Item    |   Qnty    |   ProdSched   |
|    a      |    1      |       1       |
|    b      |    2      |       1       |
|    c      |    3      |       1       |
|    a      |    4      |       2       |
|    b      |    5      |       2       |
|    c      |    6      |       2       |
```

Is there a way I can output it like this using SQL `SELECT`?

```
|   Item    |   ProdSched(1)(Qnty)  |   ProdSched(2)(Qnty)  |
|    a      |           1           |       4               |
|    b      |           2           |       5               |
|    c      |           3           |       6               |
```

Comment: Please learn to work your Shift key. Typing IN ALL CAPS IS CONSIDERED SHOUTING (and is rude). typing in all lower case makes thing harder to read. They invented the Shift key for a reason. Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get ROWS as COLUMNS (SQL Server dynamic PIVOT query)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12074939/get-rows-as-columns-sql-server-dynamic-pivot-query)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SELECT Item, 
  [ProdSched(1)(Qnty)] = MAX(CASE WHEN ProdSched = 1 THEN Qnty END),
  [ProdSched(2)(Qnty)] = MAX(CASE WHEN ProdSched = 2 THEN Qnty END)
FROM dbo.tablename
GROUP BY Item
ORDER BY Item;
```

Comment: beat me to the non-pivot version

Comment: @bluefeet and somehow I just knew you'd sweep in with a pivot version within a few minutes. +1 of course.

Answer (score 11):

You can use [`PIVOT`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) for this.  If you have a known number of values to transform, then you can hard-code the values via a static pivot:

```
select item, [1] as ProdSched_1, [2] as ProdSched_2
from 
(
  select item, qty, prodsched
  from yourtable
) x
pivot
(
  max(qty)
  for prodsched in ([1], [2])
) p
```

see [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/3a71d/2)

If the number of columns is unknown, then you can use a dynamic pivot:

```
DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

select @cols = STUFF((SELECT distinct ',' + QUOTENAME(prodsched) 
                    from yourtable
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'')

set @query = 'SELECT item,' + @cols + ' from 
             (
              select item, qty, prodsched
              from yourtable
            ) x
            pivot 
            (
                max(qty)
                for prodsched in (' + @cols + ')
            ) p '

execute(@query)
```

see [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/3a71d/3)

Answer (score 0):

Let's hit this in two phases. First, although this is not the exact format you wanted, you can get the data you asked for as follows:

```
Select item, ProdSched, max(qty)
  from Item1
 group by item,ProdSched
```

Now, to get the data in the format you desired, one way of accomplishing it is a PIVOT table. You can cook up a pivot table in SQL Server as follows:

```
Select item, [1] as ProdSched1, [2] as ProdSched2
from ( Select Item, Qty, ProdSched
         from item1 ) x
Pivot ( Max(qty) for ProdSched in ([1],[2]))  y
```