# Transposing data into multiple columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot

I have numbers of clients and each client has 67 records.

The record contains Activities, Dates, IDs, flags and many other columns.

I would like the Activities names to be the headings and Dates underneath to those Activity headings.

I am trying to explain it more using the tables below. This is the current output:

```
Client  Activity    Date 
1       A           21/15
1       B           5/5/2012
1       C           51/3115
1       D           54/6/84
2       A           8/6/99
2       B           1/1/2011
2       C           8/4
2       D           9/81/1
3       A           6/51/8
3       B           1/61/8
3       C           1/31
3       D           3/2/1
```

And I would like it to be:

```
Client      A       B         C         D
1           21/15   5/5/2012  51/31/15  54/6/84
2           8/6/99  1/1/2011  8/4       9/81/1
3           6/51/8  1/61/8    1/31      3/2/1
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get ROWS as COLUMNS (SQL Server dynamic PIVOT query)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12074939/get-rows-as-columns-sql-server-dynamic-pivot-query)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You will want to use the [`PIVOT`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) function for this. If you know the number of columns to transform then you can hard-code it via a static pivot:

```
select *
from
(
  select client, activity, dt
  from yourtable
) x
pivot
(
  max(dt)
  for activity in ([A], [B], [C], [D])
) p
```

see [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d7ff9/1)

If you have an unknown number of columns then use a dynamic version:

```
DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

select @cols = STUFF((SELECT distinct ',' + QUOTENAME(activity) 
                    from yourtable
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'')

set @query = 'SELECT client,' + @cols + ' from 
             (
              select client, activity, dt
              from yourtable
            ) x
            pivot 
            (
                max(dt)
                for activity in (' + @cols + ')
            ) p '

execute(@query)
```

see [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d7ff9/2)

Finally, this can also be done with a `CASE` statement and an aggregate function (See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d7ff9/3)):

```
select client,
  max(case when activity = 'A' then dt end) as A,
  max(case when activity = 'B' then dt end) as B,
  max(case when activity = 'C' then dt end) as C,
  max(case when activity = 'D' then dt end) as D
from yourtable
group by client
```

Comment: Thanks for the 2nd option. Helped out tremendously.