# How can I return several text fields with the same ID number in one row in SQL server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot

I have table:

```
    ID   Note
1   1    aaa
2   1    bbb
3   1    ccc
4   2    ddd
5   2    eee
6   2    fff
```

I need to return it as:

```
   ID   Note1   Note2   Note3
1  1    aaa     bbb     ccc
2  2    ddd     eee     fff
```

Thank you!

Comment: Using a `PIVOT` See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410%28v=sql.105%29.aspx for more details

Comment: Is there always three of them? if 4,2,'ddd; was 4,2,'zzz' wouls you be happy with zzz being in Note1 column?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get ROWS as COLUMNS (SQL Server dynamic PIVOT query)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12074939/get-rows-as-columns-sql-server-dynamic-pivot-query)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [`PIVOT`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) function for this type of query.  If you have a known number of columns, then you can hard-code the values:

```
select *
from
(
  select id, note,
    'Note' + 
       cast(row_number() over(partition by id order by id) as varchar(10)) col
  from yourtable
) x
pivot
(
  max(note)
  for  col in ([Note1], [Note2], [Note3])
) p
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/5969b/4)

If you are going to have an unknown number of `notes` that you want to turn into columns, then you can use dynamic sql:

```
DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

select @cols = STUFF((SELECT distinct ',' 
                      + QUOTENAME('Note' + 
                       cast(row_number() over(partition by id order by id) as varchar(10))) 
                    from yourtable
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'')

set @query = 'SELECT id,' + @cols + ' from 
             (
               select id, note,
                ''Note'' + 
                   cast(row_number() over(partition by id order by id) as varchar(10)) col
              from yourtable
            ) x
            pivot 
            (
                max(note)
                for col in (' + @cols + ')
            ) p '

execute(@query)
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/caa7c/2)

Both will produce the same results.

```
| ID | NOTE1 | NOTE2 | NOTE3 |
------------------------------
|  1 |   aaa |   bbb |   ccc |
|  2 |   ddd |   eee |   fff |
```

Or if you do not want to use the `PIVOT` function, then you can use an aggregate function with a `CASE` statement:

```
select id,
  max(case when rn = 1 then note else '' end) Note1,
  max(case when rn = 2 then note else '' end) Note2,
  max(case when rn = 3 then note else '' end) Note3
from
(
  select id, note,
    row_number() over(partition by id order by id) rn
  from yourtable
) src
group by id
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/caa7c/3)

Comment: Thank you for quick answer! I've got "Operand data type text is invalid for max operator." message. Data type for "note" column is "text". How can I fix it? Thanks!

Comment: You will have to `cast(note as varchar())` in the inner query before you apply the `max()` aggregate