# how to use pivot when column headers are coming from database

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2, pivot

I am getting data in the following format from a sql table:

```
DisplayName     PropertySystemName     PropertyDefaultName     PropertyValue
S1                  P1                    Property 1              Value 1
S1                  P2                    Property 2              Value 2
S1                  P3                    Property 3              Value 3
S1                  P4                    Property 4              Value 4
S1                  P5                    Property 5              Value 5
S1                  P6                    Property 6              Value 6
S1                  P7                    Property 7              Value 7
S1                  P8                    Property 8              Value 8
S1                  P9                    Property 9              Value 9
S1                  P10                   Property 10             Value 10
```

This is the desired output:

```
DisplayName   Property 1   Property 2 Property 3
S1               Value 1     Value 2    Value 3
```

This is the query i have but it does not produce the desired output.

```
Select me.DisplayName,
     Min(Case PropertySystemName When 'P1' Then PropertyValue End) PropertyDefaultName,
     Min(Case PropertySystemName When 'P2' Then PropertyValue End) PropertyDefaultName,
     Min(Case PropertySystemName When 'P3' Then PropertyValue End) PropertyDefaultName
FROM vManagedEntity me
```

This is the output of above query:

```
DisplayName   PropertyDefaultName   PropertyDefaultName PropertyDefaultName
S1               Value 1                   Value 2           Value 3
```

How do i modify the query in order to produce the desired output without hard coding the Column Header as it is already present in the table.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get ROWS as COLUMNS (SQL Server dynamic PIVOT query)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12074939/get-rows-as-columns-sql-server-dynamic-pivot-query)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot use the value from the `PropertyDefaultName` column as a column header unless you use dynamic sql. Using Dynamic SQL will allow you to pull the column values and the header names directly from the tables:

```
DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @colNames AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

select @cols = STUFF((SELECT distinct ',' + QUOTENAME(PropertySystemName) 
                    from vManagedEntity
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'')

select @colNames = STUFF((SELECT ',' + QUOTENAME(PropertySystemName) 
                          + ' as '+ replace(PropertyDefaultName, ' ', '')
                    from vManagedEntity
                    group by PropertySystemName, PropertyDefaultName
                    order by cast(replace(PropertySystemName, 'P', '') as int)
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'')

set @query = 'SELECT DisplayName, ' + @colNames + ' from 
             (
                select DisplayName, PropertySystemName,
                   PropertyValue
                from vManagedEntity
            ) x
            pivot 
            (
                min(PropertyValue)
                for PropertySystemName in (' + @cols + ')
            ) p '

execute(@query)
```

See [SQL Fiddle with demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/735d9/14)

The result is:

```
| DISPLAYNAME | PROPERTY1 | PROPERTY2 | PROPERTY3 | PROPERTY4 | PROPERTY5 | PROPERTY6 | PROPERTY7 | PROPERTY8 | PROPERTY9 | PROPERTY10 |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|          S1 |   Value 1 |   Value 2 |   Value 3 |   Value 4 |   Value 5 |   Value 6 |   Value 7 |   Value 8 |   Value 9 |   Value 10 |
```