# showing rows of table as columns based on some ID

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, pivot

I have a table like

```
 ID     option
 1      optionA
 1      optionB
 1      optionC
 1      optionD
```

And I want a result like:

```
ID    A        B       C       D
1  optionA  optionB optionC optionD
```

What is the best way to do this?

Query which i have tried is

```
select * from TableName PIVOT (option for ID = 2674 )) as abc
```

this will not work since PIVOT expects aggregated function..

I have also tried COALESCE like this

```
declare @t table(num VARCHAR(100))
insert into @t 
    select choice FROM QuestionAnswers where QuestionID=2674
select num from @t
declare @s varchar(8000)
select  @s = COALESCE(@s + ',', '') + num
from    @t
exec('select '+@s)
```

but this doesn't work as well..

Comment: What have you tried? Post some working queries, does not matter if the result is incorrect, is a starting point and maybe you are not far from the solution.

Comment: @rahul have you tried my ans ?

Comment: i have tried PIVOT like this select * from QuestionAnswers
PIVOT (choice for QuestionId = 2674 )) as abc; but this will not work since PIVOT expects some aggregated function...

Comment: @vikas your answer is unlikely to work for him, unless his database is exactly the same as the one you took the example from.

Comment: @Rahul, edit your question and post there the query you have tried and the result or the error if there was an error. That way others don't need to read all the comments to seek for corrections or modifications on the question.

Comment: i have also tried some example with COALESCE but didn't work..

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get ROWS as COLUMNS (SQL Server dynamic PIVOT query)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12074939/get-rows-as-columns-sql-server-dynamic-pivot-query)

Answer (score 4):

This type of data transformation is known as a *pivot*. In SQL Server 2005+ there is a function that will perform this data rotation for you. However, there are many ways that you can perform this data transformation.

Here is a `PIVOT` query that will work with your sample data:

```
select *
from
(
  select id, [option], right([option], 1) col
  from yourtable
) src
pivot
(
  max([option])
  for col in (a, b, c, d)
) piv
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d8073/2).

This can also be performed using an aggregate function with a `CASE` expression:

```
select id,
  max(case when col = 'a' then [option] else null end) a,
  max(case when col = 'b' then [option] else null end) b,
  max(case when col = 'c' then [option] else null end) c,
  max(case when col = 'd' then [option] else null end) d
from
(
  select  id, [option], right([option], 1) col
  from yourtable
) src
group by id
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d8073/4).

You can perform multiple joins on your table:

```
select a.id,
  a.[option] a,
  b.[option] b,
  c.[option] c,
  d.[option] d
from yourtable a
left join yourtable b
  on a.id = b.id
  and right(b.[option], 1) = 'b'
left join yourtable c
  on a.id = c.id
  and right(c.[option], 1) = 'c'
left join yourtable d
  on a.id = d.id
  and right(d.[option], 1) = 'd'
where right(a.[option], 1) = 'a'
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d8073/8)

Lastly, this can be done using dynamic sql if the values to be turned into columns is unknown:

```
DECLARE @colsName AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

select @colsName = STUFF((SELECT distinct ', ' + QUOTENAME(right([option], 1)) +' as '+ right([option], 1)
                    from yourtable
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'')

select @cols = STUFF((SELECT distinct ', ' + QUOTENAME(right([option], 1))
                    from yourtable
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'')


set @query = 'SELECT id, ' + @colsName + ' from 
             (
                select id, [option], right([option], 1) col
                from yourtable
            ) x
            pivot 
            (
                max([option])
                for col in (' + @cols + ')
            ) p '

execute(@query)
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d8073/12)

The result of all queries is:

```
| ID |       A |       B |       C |       D |
----------------------------------------------
|  1 | optionA | optionB | optionC | optionD |
```

Comment: SELECT *
FROM
(
  SELECT id, [option], right([option], 1) col
  FROM yourtable
) src
pivot
(
  max([option])
  FOR col IN (a, b, c, d)
) piv
 this will not work since my data can be anything, not only optionA, optionB etc...

Comment: @Rahul then you should look at the final version that I included in my answer, the dynamic one

Comment: @Rahul how about "Thanks for giving me a general guideline that I can learn from and explore on my own as an inquisitive programmer to better myself" ???

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE TABLE Product(Cust VARCHAR(25), Product VARCHAR(20), QTY INT)
GO
-- Inserting Data into Table
INSERT INTO Product(Cust, Product, QTY)
VALUES('KATE','VEG',2)
INSERT INTO Product(Cust, Product, QTY)
VALUES('KATE','SODA',6)
INSERT INTO Product(Cust, Product, QTY)
VALUES('KATE','MILK',1)
INSERT INTO Product(Cust, Product, QTY)
VALUES('KATE','BEER',12)
INSERT INTO Product(Cust, Product, QTY)
VALUES('FRED','MILK',3)
INSERT INTO Product(Cust, Product, QTY)
VALUES('FRED','BEER',24)
INSERT INTO Product(Cust, Product, QTY)
VALUES('KATE','VEG',3)
GO
-- Selecting and checking entires in table
SELECT *
FROM Product
GO
-- Pivot Table ordered by PRODUCT
SELECT PRODUCT, FRED, KATE
FROM (
SELECT CUST, PRODUCT, QTY
FROM Product) up
PIVOT (SUM(QTY) FOR CUST IN (FRED, KATE)) AS pvt
ORDER BY PRODUCT
GO
-- Pivot Table ordered by CUST
SELECT CUST, VEG, SODA, MILK, BEER, CHIPS
FROM (
SELECT CUST, PRODUCT, QTY
FROM Product) up
PIVOT (SUM(QTY) FOR PRODUCT IN (VEG, SODA, MILK, BEER, CHIPS)) AS pvt
ORDER BY CUST
GO
-- Unpivot Table ordered by CUST
SELECT CUST, PRODUCT, QTY
FROM
(
SELECT CUST, VEG, SODA, MILK, BEER, CHIPS
FROM (
SELECT CUST, PRODUCT, QTY
FROM Product) up
PIVOT
( SUM(QTY) FOR PRODUCT IN (VEG, SODA, MILK, BEER, CHIPS)) AS pvt) p
UNPIVOT
(QTY FOR PRODUCT IN (VEG, SODA, MILK, BEER, CHIPS)
) AS Unpvt
GO
-- Clean up database
DROP TABLE Product
GO
```

Ref http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2008/06/07/sql-server-pivot-and-unpivot-table-examples/

**Edited**

```
DECLARE @Product TABLE (ID int, _option varchar(10) )

-- Inserting Data into Table
INSERT INTO @Product
(
    ID,
    _option
)
SELECT 1, 'optionA' UNION ALL
SELECT 1, 'optionB' UNION ALL
SELECT 1, 'optionC' UNION ALL
SELECT 1, 'optionD' 

SELECT 
    optionA, optionB, optionC, optionD
FROM (
SELECT ID, _option
FROM @Product) up
PIVOT (SUM(ID) FOR _option IN (optionA, optionB, optionC, optionD)) AS pvt
```