# Build SQL query with dynamic columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot, unpivot

My tables go as follows:

Patients table

```
PatientId   Name
1           James
...
```

Visits table

```
Date    PatientID_FK    Weight
1/1     1               220
2/1     1               210 
...
```

How can I build a query that returns

```
PatientId    Name    Visit1Date    Visit1Weight    Visit2Date    Visit2Weight    ...
1            James   1/1           220             2/1           210
2            ...
```

How can we add more columns in this way? How to write that `SELECT`? Please help.

---

Some posts on StackExchange say it is impossible for a SQL statement to handle it. Is it really so?

Comment: [What have you tried](http://www.whathaveyoutried.com)?

Comment: What RDBMS and version are you using?

Comment: just no clue how to do it. We are using SQL server 2008R2.

Comment: @njk, I just don't understand why you downvote my question. It is a reasonable question. I think many other people will benefit from the discussion. I searched for quite a while with no success. That is why I typed this question here. If you know there is a useful link, please just add here. Many of us will appreciate. Thanks.

Comment: If someone asks "How to write" without trying anything, then I will down vote. I can tell you from my brief time on SO that there are many topics on this question, and perhaps you just weren't searching for those keywords. The [down voting](http://stackoverflow.com/privileges/vote-down) privilege actually explicitly states to use it for *no-effort-expended post*.

Comment: just do a quick search with the tags [sql-server] and [pivot] and you'll get a lot of answers about this. Here is an example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14581937/showing-rows-of-table-as-columns-based-on-some-id

Comment: The "thankyou" goes to njk. Thank you for the necessary hint. A keyword `PIVOT` helps me locate the article in here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410%28v=sql.105%29.aspx

Comment: I would say anyone can find the answer if he/she knows how to ask the question. You expert knows instantly that this is about `PIVOT`. Please show some mercy to an ignorant like me who does not know how to describe for help.

Comment: @Blaise It's ok, no need to talk that way about your knowledge. This can be a place to learn, and you currently got an upvote and one downvote (so the net result is +3 rep).

Answer (score 8):

This type of data transformation will need to be done with both a `pivot` and the `unpivot` functions.  Since your visits will be unknown, then you will want to use dynamic sql.  But first, I will show you how to build the query with the values hard-coded so it makes it easier to understand how the process works.

First, you need to `UNPIVOT` the `date` and `weight` columns so the values are in the same column. This can be done using a `UNION ALL` query or the unpivot function:

**UNPIVOT:**

```
select patientid, name, rn, col, value
from
(
  select p.patientid, p.name, convert(char(5), v.date, 110) date, 
    cast(v.weight as char(5)) weight,
    row_number() over(partition by PatientID_FK order by date) rn
  from patients p
  left join visits v
    on p.patientid = v.PatientID_FK
) src
unpivot
(
  value
  for col in (date, weight)
) unpiv
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/5f471/12). The result of this query places the values of both the date and weight column into a single column with multiple rows.  Notice that I applied a `row_number()` to the records so you will be able to tell what values go with each visit:

```
| PATIENTID |  NAME | RN |    COL | VALUE |
-------------------------------------------
|         1 | James |  1 |   date | 01-01 |
|         1 | James |  1 | weight | 220   |
|         1 | James |  2 |   date | 02-01 |
|         1 | James |  2 | weight | 210   |
```

**PIVOT:**

The next step is to apply the `PIVOT` function to the items in the `col` column, but first we need to alter the name so it gives you the names that you want.

To do that I alter the `SELECT` statement slightly to add the row number to the col name:

```
select patientid, name, 'Visit'+col + cast(rn as varchar(10)) new_col, 
  value
from ...
```

This will give you the new names  which are the names that you want as columns:

```
Visitdate1 
Visitweight1
Visitdate2
Visitweight2
```

To `PIVOT` the data your query will look like the following if you hard-code the values:

```
select *
from
(
  select patientid, name, 'Visit'+col + cast(rn as varchar(10)) new_col, 
    value
  from
  (
    select p.patientid, p.name, convert(char(5), v.date, 110) date, 
      cast(v.weight as char(5)) weight,
      row_number() over(partition by PatientID_FK order by date) rn
    from patients p
    left join visits v
      on p.patientid = v.PatientID_FK
  ) src
  unpivot
  (
    value
    for col in (date, weight)
  ) unpiv
) s1
pivot
(
  max(value)
  for new_col in (Visitdate1,Visitweight1,
                  Visitdate2,Visitweight2)
) piv
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/5f471/14).

**Dynamic PIVOT:**

Now that I have explained the logic behind how this is set up, you will want to implement this same process using dynamic sql.  You dynamic sql version will be:

```
DECLARE @colsUnpivot AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @colsPivot as  NVARCHAR(MAX)

select @colsUnpivot = stuff((select ', '+quotename(C.name)
         from sys.columns as C
         where C.object_id = object_id('visits') and
               C.name not in ('PatientID_FK')
         for xml path('')), 1, 1, '')

select @colsPivot = STUFF((SELECT  ',' + quotename('Visit'+c.name 
                                          + cast(v.rn as varchar(10)))
                    from
                    (
                       select row_number() over(partition by PatientID_FK order by date) rn
                       from visits
                    ) v
                    cross apply sys.columns as C
                   where C.object_id = object_id('visits') and
                     C.name not in ('PatientID_FK')
                   group by c.name, v.rn
                   order by v.rn
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'')

set @query 
  = 'select *
      from
      (
        select patientid, name, ''Visit''+col + cast(rn as varchar(10)) new_col,
          value
        from 
        (
          select p.patientid, p.name, convert(char(5), v.date, 110) date, 
            cast(v.weight as char(5)) weight,
            row_number() over(partition by PatientID_FK order by date) rn
          from patients p
          left join visits v
            on p.patientid = v.PatientID_FK
        ) x
        unpivot
        (
          value
          for col in ('+ @colsunpivot +')
        ) u
      ) x1
      pivot
      (
        max(value)
        for new_col in ('+ @colspivot +')
      ) p'

exec(@query)
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/5f471/10)

The result from both versions is:

```
| PATIENTID |  NAME | VISITDATE1 | VISITWEIGHT1 | VISITDATE2 | VISITWEIGHT2 |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
|         1 | James |      01-01 |        220   |      02-01 |        210   |
```