# How to create a pivot query in sql server without aggregate function

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am using MS SQL SERVER 2008 and I have following data:

```
select * from account;

| PERIOD | ACCOUNT | VALUE |
----------------------------
|   2000 |   Asset |   205 |
|   2000 |  Equity |   365 |
|   2000 |  Profit |   524 |
|   2001 |   Asset |   142 |
|   2001 |  Equity |   214 |
|   2001 |  Profit |   421 |
|   2002 |   Asset |   421 |
|   2002 |  Equity |   163 |
|   2002 |  Profit |   325 |
```

I want to make them to be this:

```
| ACCOUNT | 2000 | 2001 | 2002 |
--------------------------------
|   Asset |  205 |  142 |  421 |
|  Equity |  365 |  214 |  163 |
|  Profit |  524 |  421 |  325 |
```

I've tried to query use `pivot query` but the value have to use `aggregate function` and the result is not appropriate. what should I do?

Comment: If there is only a single value for each combination of row/column for the pivot, then there is no *harm* in using any aggregate which returns its input if given a single input, e.g. `SUM`, `MAX`, `MIN`. If there *isn't* a single value for each combination, then you need to give us (and ultimately, SQL Server) a rule for figuring out what the result should be.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get ROWS as COLUMNS (SQL Server dynamic PIVOT query)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12074939/get-rows-as-columns-sql-server-dynamic-pivot-query)

Answer (score 44):

```
SELECT *
FROM
(
SELECT [Period], [Account], [Value]
FROM TableName
) AS source
PIVOT
(
    MAX([Value])
    FOR [Period] IN ([2000], [2001], [2002])
) as pvt
```

Another way,

```
SELECT ACCOUNT,
      MAX(CASE WHEN Period = '2000' THEN Value ELSE NULL END) [2000],
      MAX(CASE WHEN Period = '2001' THEN Value ELSE NULL END) [2001],
      MAX(CASE WHEN Period = '2002' THEN Value ELSE NULL END) [2002]
FROM tableName
GROUP BY Account
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo (*both queries*)](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/f8816/6)

Comment: The period is dynamic, how to create pivot without aggregate function, because i need to show all value

Answer (score 7):

Check this out as well: using `xml path` and `pivot`

**[SQLFIDDLE DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/2f2df/19)**

```
| ACCOUNT | 2000 | 2001 | 2002 |
--------------------------------
|   Asset |  205 |  142 |  421 |
|  Equity |  365 |  214 |  163 |
|  Profit |  524 |  421 |  325 |

DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

SET @cols = STUFF((SELECT distinct ',' + QUOTENAME(c.period) 
            FROM demo c
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'')

set @query = 'SELECT account, ' + @cols + ' from 
            (
                select account
                    , value
                    , period
                from demo
           ) x
            pivot 
            (
                 max(value)
                for period in (' + @cols + ')
            ) p '


execute(@query)
```

Comment: @FitrieAdytiaWibawa here is another solution and it matches your expected output :)

Comment: Excellent answer. Helped me with an SEDE query: http://data.stackexchange.com/codereview/query/167924/top-x-user-reputation?Days=60&TopX=15#graph Thanks. +1 applied