# Mysql Nested Query with two relational table

Tags: mysql, nested

```
Table reports :
id       (int)
catid    (int)
pub_date (datetime)
```

```
Table categories :
id           (int)
parent_id    (int)
```

I want to get the report results with count(id) 's and group by catid's parent_id.

For example :

```
 Date           Count(parent_id = 1)    Count(parent_id = 2)  Count(parent_id = 3)
 
2014-02-24            2                            5                      8
```

**We should have get the results in only a line per day.**

Thanks too much in advance.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to create a pivot query in sql server without aggregate function](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14618316/how-to-create-a-pivot-query-in-sql-server-without-aggregate-function)

Answer (score 0):

How about using the below query ([**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/1b2162/1/0)):

```
SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN r.id = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS PID_1,
       SUM(CASE WHEN r.id = 2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS PID_2,
       SUM(CASE WHEN r.id = 3 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS PID_3
FROM reports AS r
INNER JOIN categories AS c ON c.parent_id = r.id
GROUP BY r.pub_date
```

Comment: the right database structure is here (http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/178ed)

thanks for your help.

Comment: ***@vural***, how about the following [**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/178ed/7/0)?  Is this what you are looking for?  FYI, in your SQL fiddle the only date that `categories` is linking to in `reports` is **2014-02-24** so you only get one record returned.  If there were more dates that `categories` is linking to then you would get more records, one for each date.  Also, there is no `0` id in reports.

Comment: I have lots of datas in my reports table. So I can not use the query. Reports' date's are different from each other and their forms are like datetime (Y-m-d H:i:s) in db. I clearly want get the result in order of reports' cat_id's parent_id.

Thank your interest.

Comment: ***@vural***, I am sorry but I don't fully follow you.  Can you update your question showing sample data in both tables?  Then, show exactly what the output would look like.