# How to get same results as this pivot query without using PIVOT, is there any other way to do this

Tags: sql-server

How to get same results as this pivot query without using PIVOT, is there any other way to do this

```
SELECT 'AverageCost' AS Cost_Sorted_By_Production_Days, 
[0], [1], [2], [3], [4]
FROM
(SELECT DaysToManufacture, StandardCost 
    FROM Production.Product) AS SourceTable
PIVOT
(
AVG(StandardCost)
FOR DaysToManufacture IN ([0], [1], [2], [3], [4])
) AS PivotTable;
```

Comment: Select DaysToManufacture, StandardCost from Product

Comment: And how to calculate average cost

Comment: I mean is there any other way instead of using pivot

Comment: to get same results

Comment: What results?...

Comment: Instead of using pivot to calculate average cost for daystomanufacture...Is there any other way to write query. Pivot is kind of confusing

Comment: **Why** are you seeking to avoid `pivot`? The reason may preclude other features/functions and so people could easily suggest other approaches that you'd also reject.

Comment: Just checking if there is any other way

Comment: Yes there are other ways. You could use a cross tab or conditional aggregation.

Comment: Check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14618316/how-to-create-a-pivot-query-in-sql-server-without-aggregate-function

Comment: @SrinivasaRao - they're currently using `AVG`. That would be an unusual aggregate to "accidentally" be using if they didn't think aggregation was necessary.