# Dynamically create more columns in SQL Server 2012 query

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have a SQL table with `[Items]` and their associated `[Cost]`, and I am looking to create a histogram showing cost distribution. This is my (working) query used to create bins:

```
SELECT
    [$0-$25]=COUNT(CASE WHEN [Cost]>=0 AND [Cost]<25 THEN 1 END),
    [$25-$50]=COUNT(CASE WHEN [Cost]>=25 AND [Cost]<50 THEN 1 END)
    --etc.
FROM 
    table_name
```

The cost range can vary wildly for different items in the table - in other words a highest cost cannot be hard-coded. What's the best way to start at `$0` and create additional `$25` columns as needed? I think the solution involves using `MAX([Cost])` and `PIVOT` together, but I'm not sure how to go about it.

Comment: If you're just getting this data from the table, you might be better of by getting the data in rows in stead of colums. You could use this query:
    select count(Cost/25) as number,(cost/25) * 25 as costrange  from table group by Cost/25 order by 2

Answer (score 0):

If you are okay with rows, you can do this:

```
SELECT  CAST(CAST([Cost] AS INT)/25 * 25 AS VARCHAR) + '-' + 
        CAST(CAST([Cost] AS INT)/25 * 25 + 25 AS VARCHAR) AS Range, count(*) As cnt
FROM    Table_Name
group by CAST(CAST([Cost] AS INT)/25 * 25 AS VARCHAR) + '-' + 
        CAST(CAST([Cost] AS INT)/25 * 25 + 25 AS VARCHAR)
```

If you want to transpose the results, you'll have to write some dynamic sql. something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12074939/get-rows-as-columns-sql-server-dynamic-pivot-query).

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to create a stored procedure like this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[SP_Test]
    @MaxValue decimal(5,2),
    @StepValue decimal(2,2)
AS
BEGIN

DECLARE @SQL nvarchar(max) = '';
DECLARE @ItemsNo decimal(2,2) = @MaxValue / @StepValue;

;WITH CTE(s)  AS (
    SELECT 0
    UNION ALL
    SELECT s + 1
    FROM CTE 
    WHERE s < @ItemsNo - 1)
SELECT @SQL = @SQL  + CASE WHEN @SQL = '' THEN '' ELSE ',' END 
                    + '[$' + CAST((s * @StepValue) AS nvarchar(5)) 
                    + '-$' + CAST(((s + 1) * @StepValue) AS nvarchar(5)) 
                    + ']=COUNT(CASE WHEN [Cost]>=' + CAST((s * @StepValue) AS nvarchar(5))
                    + ' AND [Cost]<' + CAST(((s + 1) * @StepValue) AS nvarchar(5)) 
                    + ' THEN 1 END)'
FROM CTE

SET @SQL = 'SELECT ' + @SQL + ' FROM table_name'
EXEC(@SQL)

END
```

Now you can run stored procedure like this:

```
EXEC [dbo].[SP_Test] 
     @MaxValue = 100.0, 
     @StepValue = 25.0
```